# Java InputStream Malfunction

Tags: java, inputstream

When I run the following code segment in debug mode, as soon as I execute the line `str=in.readUTF()`, program stops.

```
InputStream sin=socket.getInputStream();
DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(sin);

String str="";
str=in.readUTF();

System.out.println("This line is not reached");
```

I use netbeans. Although no exception is shown, the program stops. While in debugging mode, initially, the `str=in.readUTF()` line is green but when I press *F7 or F8* to continues, the green line turns pink and program stops.

Comment: You should go over your [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1673627/user1673627?tab=questions) and [accept some answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that people will answer your questions in the future.

Comment: I believe this blocks until there is something to read. Is there anything being posted to the socket?

Answer (score 1):

As documented at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF() the calls reads a string from the stream and returns it.

Your debugger is just waiting for input.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you wrote the data with `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()` you can't read it with `DataInputStream.readUTF()`. Possibly you should be using `readLine()`. It depends entirely on how you wrote the data, which you haven't told us.